# iPhone - How prevent an UIWebView to draw/update its content

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, uiwebview, hidden

I have some view inside wich there are an UIWebView. For performance reasons, I do not allocate the Web view on the fly, but it is set into IB and linked with a class outlet. When I do not need it, I set its `hidden` property to YES.

But, after having profiled my application because of performance problems, I noticed that when resizing the views containing those UIWebViews, they take a huge amount of time in :

```
[WebFrame(WebInternal) _drawRect:contentsOnly:]
```

So to prevent this, I also set their `scalesPageToFit` to NO, but this doesn't change anything.
I've tested deleting them from the project, and yes, the resize of the view is really much faster.

So how can I prevent the UIWebViews that are hidden to eat my process time in useless drawing work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the UIWebView try removing it from the container view using removeFromSuperview. When you want to make it visible again add it back as a subview. This should keep the instance of the UIWebView in memory and prevent it from redrawing when it is not visible.